# Vue 3 Mono Repo how to use the root dev dependancies

Tags: node.js, typescript, vue.js

I setup a mono repo using Ionic and Vue 3 the only issue is that in my child apps I still need to add the following into package.json. How can I use the root devDepenencies?

```
"devDependencies": {
   "@vue/cli-plugin-typescript": "~5.0.0-rc.1"
},
```

Here is my structure:

```
apps
  - app1
    - package.json <-- here i have to add devDependency
    - tsconfig.json
  - app2
    - package.json <-- here i have to add devDependency
    - tsconfig.json
package.json <-- devDependency is in here too
tsconfig-base.json
```

Everything works this way but it creates a node_modules folder with a ton of dependencies in each child app. I'd like to avoid that if possible.

If I remove the devDependency I get the following error:

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './src/main.js'
```

So its not seeing the dependency and thinking I'm using js but in fact i'm using typescript.

I tried setting the baseUrl in the tsconfigs but nothing has worked yet. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of configuring vue to find it you could set up a path link:

```json
"devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-typescript": "link:../node_modules/@vue/cli-plugin-typescript"
}
```

Comment: I get this error trying that when adding to the child package.json
Unsupported URL Type "link:": link:../node_modules/@vue/cli-plugin-typescript

Comment: Hmm could try `npm install ../node_modules/wherever`

Answer (score 0):

This would likely be your solution if you're using a monorepo. Add the following to your app1 and app2 package.json:

```
{
  "vuePlugins": {
   "resolveFrom": "insert path to parent package.json here"
  }
}
```

See documentation here: https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/plugins-and-presets.html#installing-plugins-in-an-existing-project